# WinForms RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

OK. Simple as possible: I want to inject a RichTextFormat comment (e.g. '{\*\atnid 1}' into the RichTextBox.Rtf;. That command doesn't show up in the richtextbox display area, which is the way I want it. The trouble is, there's no way I can see to put that comment in using C# and .NET. Adding it as a string adds an extra backslash each time, since the backslash char is the escape char, and the RTB displays it.

How to get'{\*\atnid 1}' into the Rtf buffer without additional backslashes being added by .NET?

Comment: That should have been '\\\*'

Comment: Which one of them should have been `\\*`?

Comment: Are you trying to put the command string in the box as information -- that is, as text -- or as a means of getting the RichTextBox to do something?

Comment: You can change the rtfcontrol.Rtf property __if__ you know what you are doing..

Comment: Please can you edit your question to clarifiy it a little? As Ann says, we aren't sure what you're trying to achieve, and as such will have trouble helping you. Posting your code will also help us to understand.

Comment: Trying to add '\\*' (one backslash and an asterisk) to Rtf. This character combo will not display in RTB, so it will act as a placeholder in the Rtf.. C# requires an escaping backslash in a string, so when it is added to RTF via AppendText it displays as backslash *. I'm trying to find a way to inject rtf control code into the RTB such that it won't display, but will still be in the rtf. You cn do this with Notepad, but VS raises an unrecognized escape exception if the string has only one backslash.

Comment: Trying to add '\\*' (one backslash and an asterisk) to RTB.Rtf. This character combo will not display in RTB, so it will act as a placeholder for me in the Rtf.. C# requires an escaping backslash in a string, so when it is added to RTF via RTB.AppendText it displays as '\*. I don't want it to display at all. I'm trying to find a way to inject rtf control code into the RTB such that it won't display, but will still be in the rtf. You can do this with Notepad, but VS raises an unrecognized escape exception if the string has only one backslash.

Comment: (OK, Stackoverflow has the same issue with backslashes, I see.)  Question is, simply: how to add non-displaying text into RTB using .NET. If RTB had an override on its AppendText method that would accemt a char array, that would solve the problem, but nooooo.

Comment: And I have read the MS rtf spec, so I know about the comment/annotation format, but trying to get it into the rtf buffer programmatically with C# is fighting me every step of the way.

Comment: The WinForms RichTextBox only supports a subset of the RTF spec.  There are ways to use a more updated version, but there are still a ton of limitations.  If the RichTextBox doesn't recognize an rtf command, it will just eliminate it.  You could use hidden text as a way to mark a position, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, Lars Tech. I'm relatively new to C#, but have been coding for Windows for a long time (since there WAS Windows). It seems the problem is still there: how to get '\v'..'\v0' into the rtf without C# adding the escape backslashes.

Comment: OK, Lars Tech. Your answer solved my problem. Thank you!